# Как получить функцию из таблицы?

Tags: sql, функции, oracle, plsql

Создал пробную (демо) функцию для сложения двух чисел:

```
create or replace FUNCTION Addition (x number, y number) RETURN number AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (x+y);   
END; 
/
```

Далее, допустим есть такая таблица с данными:

```
Seq  Inputl  lnput2  Function
---  ------  ------  ----------------
A         1       2  Addition
B         3       4  Subtraction
C         5       6  Addition
D         7       8  Addition
E         9      10  Addition
```

Хотел бы вызывать функции указанные в таблице в PL/SQL примерно так:

```
declare
    type datarows is table of tab1%rowtype;
    data datarows;
    result number;
begin
    select * 
    bulk collect into data 
    from tab1 order by Seq asc;
    for i in 1 .. data.count loop
        result := data(i).function(data(i).Input1, data(i).Input2);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

> PLS-00224: object 'DATA(I).FUNCTION' must be of type function or array to be used this way

Понятно, что так нельзя вызвать функцию.

Есть ли какой-то другой путь решения?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Derive function from table in PLSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63021841) от участника [@Deepak Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12354924/deepak-sharma)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63021841

Answer (score 3):

Mожно создать функцию, которая примет как параметр имя операции из таблицы, например, `Addition` или `Subtraction`:

```
create or replace function doOperation (operation varchar2, x number, y number ) return number as
begin
    return case initcap (operation)
        when 'Addition' then x + y
        when 'Subtraction' then x - y
        end;
end doOperation;
/

with t (seq, input1, input2, operation) as ( 
    select 'A', 1,  2, 'Addition' from dual union all
    select 'C', 5,  6, 'Subtraction' from dual)
select t.*, doOperation (operation, input1, input2) as result
from  t;
```

Результат:

```
SEQ     INPUT1     INPUT2 OPERATION       RESULT
--- ---------- ---------- ----------- ----------
A            1          2 Addition             3
B            3          4 Addition             7
C            5          6 Subtraction         -1
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63023745) от участника [@William Robertson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230471/william-robertson)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Выглядит так, что результат должен быть вычислен только после `fetch`, иначе виртуальных колонок было бы достаточно.

Можно просто сохранить все колонки и операции с ними как объекты, т.е воспользоваться обьектно-реляционной моделью данных:

```
create table tab1 of operation
/
insert into tab1 values (addition    ('A', 1, 2));
insert into tab1 values (subtraction ('B', 4, 3));
commit;
```

Окончательный PL/SQL блок будет выглядеть почти идентично фрагменту кода из вопроса:

```
declare
    type arr is table of operation;
    data arr;
begin
    select value (t)  
    bulk collect into data from tab1 t order by seq asc;
    for i in 1..data.count loop
        if data(i) is of (addition) then
            dbms_output.put_line ('Result of addition    '||data(i).eval);
         elsif data(i) is of (subtraction) then
            dbms_output.put_line ('Result of subtraction '||data(i).eval);
         end if;
    end loop;
end;
/
Result of addition    3
Result of subtraction 1
```

Создание используемых в примере объектов:

```
create or replace type operation force is object (
    seq varchar2 (3),
    member function eval return number
) not final not instantiable 
/
create or replace type bioperation under operation (
    arg1 number, arg2 number,
    constructor function bioperation  (arg1 number, arg2 number) return self as result
) not final not instantiable 
/
create or replace type body bioperation is
    constructor function bioperation (arg1 number, arg2 number) return self as result is 
    begin
        self.arg1 := arg1; self.arg2 := arg2;
        return; 
    end;
end;
/
create or replace type addition under bioperation (
    overriding member function eval return number
) final
/
create or replace type body addition is
    overriding member function eval return number is
    begin return (arg1 + arg2);
    end;
end;
/
create or replace type subtraction under bioperation (
    overriding member function eval return number
) final
/
create or replace type body subtraction as
    overriding member function eval return number is
    begin return (arg1 - arg2);
    end;
end;
/
```

---

**Заметки на полях**

Такой подход для простых задач требует больше кода, выигрыш станет впервые заметен, если кол-во и сложность операций значительно возрастёт. Так что, для простого примера как в вопросе предложенное решение в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1161693/217579), более чем достаточно. В общем случае, проще написать "грязное" решение с динамическим SQL, чем "чистое" объектно-ориентированное решение.